# Strong convergence of two probability measures implies limit Radon-Nikodym derivative swap?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal{F} )$ is a measurable space and that $\{ \mu_n \}_{n\geq1}$ and $\{ \nu_n \}_{n\geq1}$are sequences of probability measures that converge STRONGLY to measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively.  Supposing that $\forall n\geq 1$, $\mu_n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu_n$, can anyone provide  necessary conditions for the following to hold?  $$\forall\omega\in\Omega, \hspace{.1in}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{d\mu_n}{d\nu_n}(\omega)=\frac{d\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\mu_n}{d\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\nu_n}(\omega),$$ where for each $n\geq1$, $\frac{d\mu_n}{d\nu_n}(\omega)$ denotes the image of the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measures $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ at $\omega$.  Any input on the case when the probability measures converge weakly is also appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you replace strong convergence by total variation convergence the statement always holds. For strong convergence, maybe you could craft a dominating measure by taking $\nu/2 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \nu_n/{2^n}$ ?

Comment: hmm... can you elaborate a bit as to why tv convergence implies the above?

Comment: Actually nevermind my previous comment.  The paper does not provide the convergence.

Comment: Maybe figure out how to delete your question, instead of replacing it with nonsense.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post. You can delete the post. There should be a delete button under the tags.

Comment: Do **not** do that again.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, does anyone know how to remove your own comment from a post?  The "X" operation under the comment seems to not work at all.